# Apache mod_rewrite ending periods

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to better understand Apache's mod_rewrite, and am having unexpected results.  I've  tried many different expressions, but nothing seems to behave how I understand it should.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Using `www.domain.com/item1/item2/item3` yields `item1/item2/item3`
Using `www.domain.com/item1/item2/item3.php` yields `item1/item2/item3.php`
Using `www.domain.com/item1/item2/item3...........` yields `item1/item2/item3`

**Why is it not `item1/item2/item3...........`?**

Strangely, if the URL is `www.domain.com/item1/item2/item3..........a`, the route is what I expect, `item1/item2/item3..........a`

I've tried a few other regular expressions, but they act similarly.

Thank you.

Comment: Been looking for documentation for this behavior, but couldn't find it. Seems other people have the same experience though: mod_rewrite strips trailing dots: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280805/trailing-dots-being-stripped-from-url

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the link.  I wasn't able to find that one.  Sounds like this is the correct behavior of mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I still haven't found any documentation explaining why Apache/.htaccess/mod_rewrite behaves this way, I do have an alternative, in case anyone comes across this.

Instead of using .htaccess to pass the requested filename into a querystring variable, like `route` in my question above, in PHP there are some server variables that can be used.  So, I changed my logic in index.php from reading the querystring to:

```
trim( $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'], "/" );
```

The REDIRECT_URL (and REQUEST_URI) server variables will retain the trailing dots, and the trim will get the leading and trailing slashes off, similar to what happens with the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem and it seems like a bug of Apache on Windows platform. However, it works on Linux.

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48687