# mod_rewrite and dot at END of URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, period

I have been developing a shop, which uses mod_rewrite to allow us to make the URIs more readable, for instance:

http://www.example.com/shop/Tools

Will be rewritten to

http://www.example.com/index.php?area=shop&folder=Tools

My rewrite rule is as follows:

`RewriteRule ^shop/([^?#]+) index.php?area=shop&folder=$1 [NC,QSA,L]`

However, this breaks when the folder name ends in . (dot), as I discovered when testing with a folder name ending in "etc."

It seems any trailing dots are totally removed before `$_GET` has been populated. If I put another character after the dot, it's fine, if the URI ends in any number of dots, they are removed

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Doh, been searching for ages and didn't find these,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383339/mod-rewrite-with-trailing-period-in-url

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144079/apache-mod-rewrite-ending-periods

Comment: Actually, a little more digging and testing has revealed that this is a Windows only problem, if anyone could shed any light on this I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to exclude "?" and "#" in `RewriteRule` since it operates only on URI (path), without query-string or anchor.

So, this is enough:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/(.+) index.php?area=shop&folder=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

That being said, this does not change the fact that **dots** get stripped.

This may be a result of `MultiViews` being on. This option makes Apache try and resolve the URIs disregarding extensions.

So, add this as well:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: Thanks Poncha, that didn't help though

Comment: Apparently it's a Windows issue (it works fine on my linux server)

Comment: Well, you can use the solution provided in one of the links you've found and parse the `REDIRECT_URI` (inside php) afterwards to overcome this issue. That is if you care about it running on windows ;)

Comment: Not in this particular instance but it'd still be nice to know :) REDIRECT_URI isn't available on my machine, will look into it more